Do I need to add extra quotes in a single args entry containing spaces for a cppdbg launch config?
I can build the source code for the Linux "parted" command from my command line and then run a command like this from the command line and it works as expected:
sudo /home/flex/apps/sbin/parted-3.6.6 -s -a opt /dev/loop0 "print resizepart 1 46280703s print"

Now I am trying to set it up to debug the source code for "parted" in MS Visual Studio Code.
I have a launch.json like this...
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "/home/flex/apps/sbin/parted-3.6.6",
        "args": ["-s", "-a", "opt", "/dev/loop0", "'print resizepart 1 46280703s print'"],
        "miDebuggerPath": "/home/flex/gdb",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}

When I run that I am getting an error that the parted arguments are not recognised correctly so how do I supply the arguments? Notice how I have added quotes around the last argument because it has spaces in it and I usually have to do that when running the command in a shell. Is that correct?

I wonder if the use of quotes within the final argument might be the problem?  Try dropping the single quotes from "'print resizepart 1 46280703s print'", see if that helps at all...

@Andrew Yes that was the problem, thanks a lot!

No, you don't need to add extra quotes around args entries for a cppdbg launch config. It's already a JSON array of strings. cpptools has all it needs to know when it needs to do that quoting itself, and it does / should.
